# Yet another "focus() won't work"

Tags: jquery, focus

I tried building something that a few suggested as a universal way to help a user put something to clipboard, to wit, popup a modal dialog with the correct text selected and invite the user to press Ctrl-C/Opt-C. I'm mostly there, but I just can't seem to get focus to focus on the input box. onclick() heads to this simple function:

```
function clipboard()
{
var tag = $("#tag").text();
$("#clipboardModal").modal('show');
$("#copyTag").val(tag);
$("#copyTag")[0].focus();
$("#copyTag").select();
}
```

I already figured out that $(x).focus() doesn't set focus and that you need to do either $(x).get(0).focus() or $(x)[0].focus() to do the actual focusing. However, I never get focus to the input field. Chrome keeps focus stubbornly on the button clicked that calls clipboard(). Explorer puts the focus on the modal dialog just before the X close button. I can tab a couple times and I'm in the input box. But in either case, I'm not getting what I want.  (Note: the select() above is irrelevant because it never gets focus there to begin with.) For completeness, here's the html:

```
<!-- START: clipboardModal - modal dialog for selecting gadgets -->
<div id="clipboardModal" class="modal fade fuelux">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Your Tag</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="gadgetChangeID">
                <p>Press Ctrl-C/Opt-C to copy to clipboard</p>
            </div>
            <input id="copyTag" type="text" />
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: clipboardModal -->
```

Any clues how I can get the focus to my input field?

Comment: You shouldn't need to get the index of the jQuery array when selecting on an id I don't think... There should only be one item per id. Have you tried just `$("#copyTag").focus();`?

Comment: `[0]` returns the plain html element out of the jquery array.

Comment: @Banana, yes but I don't think you should have to do that in this case. See 3d example [here](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: $("#copyTag").focus(), according to the jQuery documentation calls the focus trigger. It doesn't actually set focus. This was described in a number of other stack overflow answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
function clipboard(){
    var tag = $("#tag").text();
    $("#clipboardModal").modal('show');

    $('#clipboardModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#copyTag").val(tag);
        $("#copyTag").focus();
        $("#copyTag").select();
    });
}
```

This focuses the input text only after the modal is actually shown.

The on shown code can even be outside the function

```
$('#clipboardModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#copyTag").val(tag);
    $("#copyTag").focus();
    $("#copyTag").select();
});
function clipboard(){
    var tag = $("#tag").text();
    $("#clipboardModal").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That was the solution. I suspected something like that, but didn't know exactly what.